# How to create a commit that makes one branch identical to another?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Assume I have two branches: `master` and `deploy`. The `master` branch is the current "edge" code - feature and bug fix branches are merged to `master`. The `deploy` branch on the other hand is what my CI system watches to trigger automatic deployment. The normal workflow will be that once code is considered "good" on `master`, it's merged to `deploy` which causes an automatic deployment.

In testing the CI environment I made a bunch of test commits to the `deploy` branch. The commits simply made changes for changes' sake, just to test the CI trigger. There's now maybe 12 or so commits that simply make silly random (but detectable in the deployment) changes. Now that the CI is working I want to "roll back" the `deploy` branch to the current `master`.

The problem is that I don't have the ability to use `--force` on the remote repo (permissions).

Therefore what I'd like to be able to do is to somehow make a commit that will make the `master` and `deploy` branches identical. Basically I want to diff the current deploy and master branches, and add that diff as a commit to deploy. Then I can merge `deploy` into `master` which will cause no changes to be made, and the branches will be back in sync.

Just merging `master` into `deploy` right now won't work since `deploy`'s changes will be maintained.

I'm not worried about the commit history.

I know I can bring in an individual file from another commit or branch by doing `git checkout <branch> <file>`. What I'm basically looking for is "check out ALL files from another branch but do not switch to that branch." Then I can just make a commit and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge--sltstrategygt) called [ours](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-ours) like this :

```
git checkout master
git merge deploy -s ours
git checkout deploy
git merge master
git push origin HEAD
```

will make a merge commit on `deploy` which takes 0 modifications from `deploy` whatsoever, thus taking all code from `master`. But it doesn't rewrite history, and you'll be able to push `deploy` without `--force`.

Or, for the benefit of a less clunky history (thank you [eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0) for the neat trick), you can alternatively go for this approach :

```
git checkout --detach master
git merge -s ours deploy -m "setting content just like master"
git branch -f deploy
git push some-remote deploy
```

Comment: using `-s ours` is not _exactly_ the same as replacing the whole content. That will only work on pieces where there's _conflict_. So... if there's a piece on the other branch that will be merged _and_ it can do so without a conflict, _our_ change is not picked but the other branches, so you don't end up replacing all of the contents with whatever is on our branch... only the conflicting pieces. `git reset --soft` is a better suited tool for this job.

Comment: @eftshift0 Well, I checked and I still maintain my point, I think this is the correct way to take everything from one side, not only the conflicting parts. If not, what did I miss? I'd be glad to correct my views if this is not the case. What you describe applies more to `git merge -Xours`, does it not?

Comment: Actually, you are right, @RomainValeri. I was reading ours from recursive, not ours _strategy_. Let me delete my post as yours is muuuuuch simpler.

Comment: Perhaps I'd change a little bit your recipe: `git checkout deploy; git merge -m 'setting up content just like in master' master -s theirs; git push some-remote deploy` (I don't see why you want to mess up with master... keep it as it is, don't move it).

Comment: @eftshift0 I admit I too would have prefered doing it this way, but the doc says there's no `theirs` merge strategy equivalent to what `ours` does here. You have the theirs *merge option* to use like this `git merge somebranch -Xtheirs`, but (if I understand it) no `git merge -s theirs` (interestingly)

Comment: man, you are good! :-) ok.,... then you have to detach so not to move master: `git checkout --detach master; git merge -s ours deploy -m "setting content just like master"; git branch -f deploy; git push some-remote deploy`. this way you don't move master, only deploy moves.

Comment: @eftshift0 I like that, and didn't know a thing about the `--detach` option, I'll go read this, thanks a lot. Time to revamp your answer, I'd say!

Comment: Not at all... it's your answer with a little something... plus your answer has been already accepted. Your recipe actually pulls it off.... only that it intertwines both branches in a couple of revisions that actually were not necessary... but the core of the answer is to use -s ours the way you did. Rock on. Perhaps you could add a comment saying that thanks to _me_ you have this other recipe with a little detail.... but I'm fine with you getting the credit.

Comment: @eftshift0 Goes for me. Fine teamwork here :-) Feel free to edit yourself any further.

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't have to copy the files between branches (except .git directory) to reset like a caveman! :)

Comment: Though be aware that this does not add just a single commit in `deploy`.